# Generate Non-Editable PDF File From Windows Appication

Tags: vb.net, pdf, windows

I am working on windows based application. Using VB.Net.

So the question is, I want to create/generate a **`Non-editable`** PDF from vb.net window application. Can anyone please suggest some ideas or helpful links... That could help to me to solve my problem.

**Note:** *I have the idea of creating pdf file using read only but some software cracks it and make it read/write. So I do not want to do that*

Comment: *a **`Non-editable`** PDF* - What exactly do you mean by that? Non-Editable by which programs? (I ask because with a bit of knowledge anyone can manipulate any PDF if he can view it.)

Comment: yes you are right. I understand it but the thing is I was not considering to  `bit of knowledge` person. :D

Comment: ;) Unfortunately nowadays only a tiny bit of knowledge is required, numerous web services do the cracking without further ado, all one needs to know is that there are such services...

Answer (score 0):

You can use ITEXTSHARP to generate the pdf files,

But there is no way to block a user from editing it explicitly.

There is one thing which you can do.

You can generate the password protected files, doing so you can restrict a user from editing it.

Find the below links.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-generate-and-download-PDF-Report-from-database-in-ASPNet-using-iTextSharp-C-and-VBNet.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d40a40/create-simple-pdf-file-using-itextsharp-library/

Or you can use http Response:

http://pdfcrowd.com/web-html-to-pdf-net/

Feel free to ask if you have any further question.